# Skyrim's slow loading screens

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

Skyrim on the Xbox 360 has really slow loading screens on my xbox? Is there anyway of speeding up this progress or is it like this all the time?? The questions that I raise are

1. Is it the xbox that can't process the game quick enough?
2. Is it slow because of the buffering of the zone?
3. Is there any ways of speeding the process? If you already installed the game and seen no difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually looked into this once and I don't believe there is anything you can do to make it faster. I installed the game to my hard drive and the only difference I noticed was that the game stopped freezing on the occasional loading screen.

Speed-wise I don't think you can do anything. The game just runs/loads a lot of data and the Xbox's hardware is limited and can't be upgraded. It's a bit annoying but it's just something you have to endure if you wish to play.

But keep in mind, the reason the loading screens are so long is so that when you're running around actually doing something important the game (typically) won't slow down or lag.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I've come close to 90% completion as I've done nearly everything, but I gave up with 100% as the loading screens decided to annoy me.

Comment: Haha, yeah they can do that to ya. At least you got your fill before the annoyance set in :)

Answer (score 3):

You actually can make the loading screens go faster. Due to the fact that auto-saving is mainly what makes loading screens so long, the actual loading time can be cut considerably.

Go into your game settings and disable the auto-save option on travel, and it will cut the loading time down by half. Going through doors only takes a few seconds for me now, and fast-traveling a minute or more, depending on how far you're going and the amount of texture the game has to load.

Be warned, though, you're going to have to manually save a lot more often now, as the game still freezes (and you still die) without the buffer of having a save every time you go through a door.

Comment: Is that tip only for XBox or would it work on PC? I will try on my PC tonight and see if it helps (I don't think it would affect much).

Answer (score 0):

On the PC, turning off the save on menu, save on fast travel, and save through doors makes a huge difference. I'm not sure about the xBox, but I'd try that out on it too and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to make the loading screens shorter than going to setting and disabling the auto-save when fast-traveling or going through doors. The only downside to this is that you will be brought to saving the game manually a lot more because you're not going to get that life-changer auto-save any longer. I, for one, keep the auto-save and long loading screens just to be safe.

Answer (score -1):

If you are storing the games in the cloud, delete all but a few saves. The more there are the longer the cloud sync takes.

Comment: Given the context of the question, I think it is pretty clear that the user is asking about the loading transitions between levels. Not the process of loading all available save files.

Answer (score -2):

Acctually instead of pressing continue got to load and load your game it worked for me hope it works for you.